# How to find if a matrix has a column vector in MATLAB

Tags: matrices, vectors, matlab

> Imagine that $D = eye(size(A)(1))$ , being $A$ an input matrix. How can I code to appear that $A$ has $D(:,j)$ and does not have $D(:,i)$.

---

Example :
If I have a matrix like this one: $$A = \begin{matrix} 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\ 2 & 0 & 5 & 6 \\\end{matrix}$$ what can I code to appear that $A$ has $D(:,2)$ and does not have $D(:,1)$ and $D(:3)$.

Comment: Do you mean D=eye(size(A,1)) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, but there exist the function `intersect`. Probably, this one will help : `intersect(D',A','rows')`.